# Is there any Python equivalent to partial classes?

Tags: python, partial-classes

Using "new" style classes (I'm in python 3.2) is there a way to split a class over multiple files?  I've got a large class (which really should be a single class from an object-oriented design perspective, considering coupling, etc, but it'd be nice to split over a few files just for ease of editing the class.

Comment: can you put some core functionality into a base class?

Comment: The phrases "large class" and "single class from an object-oriented design perspective" don't go too well together.

Comment: @Niklas, agreed that they usually don't but occasionally do.  Most of my classes are pretty small.

Comment: @Matthew: Can you give some background info on why you think that it's a good idea that the class is so big?

Comment: Sure, I'll have to wait 'till tonight to provide a proper response with my thoughts.  For now I'll just say that I subscribe to approach of using cohesion and coupling to determine the "boundaries" of various classes.

Comment: A class doesn't have to be big for the partial classes feature, the ability to split a class across files, to be useful.

Comment: @Seth: Exactly, for example when using an extendable generated class. Part of the class is automatically generated in a file (humans shouldn't touch this file for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If your problem really is just working with a large class in an editor, the first solution I'd actually look for is a better way to break down the problem. The second solution would be a better editor, preferably one with code folding.

That said, there are a couple of ways you might break up a class into multiple files. Python lets you use a folder as a module by putting an `__init__.py` in it, which can then import things from other files. We'll use this capability in each solution. Make a folder called, say, `bigclass` first.

1. In the folder put the various `.py` files that will eventually comprise your class.  Each should contain functions and variable definitions for the eventual class, *not* classes. In `__init__.py` in the same folder write the following to join them all together.

   ```
   class Bigclass(object):

       from classdef1 import foo, bar, baz, quux
       from classdef2 import thing1, thing2
       from classdef3 import magic, moremagic
       # unfortunately, "from classdefn import *" is an error or warning

       num = 42   # add more members here if you like
   ```

   This has the advantage that you end up with a single class derived directly from `object`, which will look nice in your inheritance graphs.
2. You could use multiple inheritance to combine the various parts of your class. In your individual modules you would write a class definition for `Bigclass` with parts of the class. Then in your `__init__.py` write:

   ```
   import classdef1, classdef2, classdef3

   class Bigclass(classdef1.Bigclass, classdef2.Bigclass, classdef3.Bigclass):
       num = 42   # add more members if desired
   ```
3. If the multiple inheritance becomes an issue, you *can* use single inheritance: just have each class inherit from another one in chain fashion. Assuming you don't define anything in more than one class, the order doesn't matter. For example, `classdef2.py` would be like:

   ```
   import classdef1
   class Bigclass(classdef1.Bigclass):
        # more member defs here
   ```

   `classdef3` would import `Bigclass` from `classdef2` and add to it, and so on. Your `__init__.py` would just import the last one:

   ```
   from classdef42 import Bigclass
   ```

I'd generally prefer #1 because it's more explicit about what members you're importing from which files but any of these solutions could work for you.

To use the class in any of these scenarios you can just import it, using the folder name as the module name: `from bigclass import Bigclass`

Comment: +1 I like the first of your alternatives the best of any mentioned here so far.

Comment: Marking this answer as the solution because the other answers suggest that *usually* a large class shouldn't really be one class.  But I maintain that they do occur occassionally and this answer offers some practical ways to deal with the situation.

Comment: huh this is actually what I was looking for, wrongly I looked at it like a Mixin, but problem with Mixins (your #2 or via decorators) is that Mixins in this case will have tight coupling (because they are really a single class) and they start using each other's properties even though they do not declare them themselves. It gets very ugly soon. With a single big class, best is to break it in manageable portions.

Comment: problem with #3 is some attributes go very deep, that hurts inspections if you use a nice IDE like Pycharm. #1 seems perfect, only wish `import *` could work. BTW, for #1 it make sense to use `:type self:BigClass` and call the first argument `self` this will help inspections.

Comment: What about [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):
_Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants_?

Comment: What about PEP8: *sometimes style guide recommendations just aren't applicable. When in doubt, use your best judgment.*

Comment: #1 is actually super awesome as it even allows to use `self`: you just define something like `def test(self): return self.a + 5` in a separate file, then do the inclusion like in this answer (don't forget to create `self.a` in `__init__`), and then you can do `c = BigClass(); c.test()` and it'll work flawlessly as `self` is just a regular function argument that's passed implicitly. This is amazing!

Comment: This answer failed to answer the actual question.

Answer (score 20):

You can do this with decorators like so:

```
class Car(object):

    def start(self):
        print 'Car has started'


def extends(klass):
    def decorator(func):
        setattr(klass, func.__name__, func)
        return func
    return decorator

#this can go in a different module/file
@extends(Car)
def do_start(self):
    self.start()


#so can this
car = Car()
car.do_start()

#=> Car has started
```

Comment: Very interesting approach! I'd just like to point out that code completion probably won't work for `do_start()`. Nevertheless, I like this solution. :)

Answer (score 9):

Class definitions containing hundreds of lines do occur "in the wild" (I have seen some in popular open-source Python-based frameworks), but I believe that if you ponder what the methods are doing, it will be possible to reduce the length of most classes to a manageable point.  Some examples:

- Look for places where mostly the same code occurs more than once.  Break that code out into its own method and call it from each place with arguments.
- "Private" methods that do not use any of the object state can be brought out of the class as stand-alone functions.
- Methods that should be called only under certain conditions may indicate a need to place those methods in a subclass.

To directly address your question, it is possible to split up the definition of a class.  One way is to "monkey-patch" the class by defining it and then adding outside functions to it as methods.  Another is to use the built-in `type` function to create the class "by hand", supplying its name, any base classes, and its methods and attributes in a dictionary.  But I do not recommend doing this just because the definition would be long otherwise.  That sort of cure is worse than the disease in my opinion.

Comment: I agree that generally a large class suggests that its got more than one responsibility and shouldn't.  However, they do occur (even following best practices).

Comment: Indeed they do.  I wrote one recently for rational arithmetic that is 362 lines, including long docstrings, with all empty lines stripped out.  However I do have some `@staticmethod`s with names starting with `_`, which by my own advice should probably be moved out as functions.  That would reduce the length by about half.

Answer (score 6):

I've previously toyed around with something similar. My usecase was a class hierarchy of nodes in an abstract syntax tree, and then I wanted to put all e.g. prettyprinting functions in a separate prettyprint.py file but still have them as methods in the classes.

One thing I tried was to use a decorator that puts the decorated function as an attribute on a specified class. In my case this would mean that prettyprint.py contains lots of `def prettyprint(self)` all decorated with different `@inclass(...)`

A problem with this is that one must make sure that the sub files are always imported, and that they depend on the main class, which makes for a circular dependency, which may be messy.

```
def inclass(kls):
    """
    Decorator that adds the decorated function
    as a method in specified class
    """
    def _(func):
        setattr(kls,func.__name__, func)
        return func
    return _

## exampe usage
class C:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d

# this would be in a separate file.
@inclass(C)
def meth(self, a):
    """Some method"""
    print "attribute: %s - argument: %s" % (self.d, a)

i = C(10)
print i.meth.__doc__
i.meth(20)
```

Answer (score 3):

I've not used it, but [this package called partial](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/partial/1.0) claims to add support for partial classes.

It seems like there's a few other ways you could implement this yourself as well.

You could implement separate parts of the class as mixins in seperate files, then import them all somewhere and subclass them.

Alternatively, you could implement each of the methods of your class somewhere then in a central file import them and assign them as attributes on a class, to create the whole object.  Like so:

a.py:

```
def AFunc( self, something ):
    # Do something
    pass
```

b.py:

```
def BFunc( self, something ):
    # Do something else
    pass
```

c.py:

```
import a, b

class C:
    AFunc = a.AFunc
    BFunc = b.BFunc
```

You could even go so far as to automate this process if you really wanted - loop through all the functions provided by modules `a` and `b` and then add them as attributes on `C`.  Though that might be total overkill.

There might be other (possibly better) ways to go about it, but those are the 2 that popped into mind.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that the pythonic way of doing this is through multiple inheritance, not necessarily using mixins. Instance attributes can be added using `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` in `__init__` calls to pass arguments to baseclasses (see ‘super considered super’ presentation by Raymond Hettinger [1](https://youtu.be/EiOglTERPEo)). This also enables dependency injection and kind of forces you to think about organization of base classes (it works best if only one baseclass sets an attribute in `__init__` and all classes using the attribute inherit from it).

This does usually require you having control over the base classes (or they being written for this pattern).

Another option is using descriptors returning functions through `__get__` to add functionality to classes in a decoupled way.

You could also look at `__init_subclass__` to add e.g. methods to classes during class generation (i think added in python 3.6, but check)

Answer (score -1):

First I'd like to say that something this complicated it probably not a good idea just to make finding your place in the class easier - it would be best to add comments, highlight sections etc.  However, I see two ways you could do this:

1. Write the class in several files, then read them in as text, concatenate them and `exec` the resulting string.
2. Create a separate class in each file, then inherit them all into a master class as mixins.  However, if you're subclassing another class already this could lead to MRO problems.  You could get around this by creating a metaclass for your master class which manually resolves the MRO, but this could get messy.

The easiest would be the first option.

Comment: Be careful with `exec`.  You have to supply the namespace that the code should execute "in".  Security risks, etc.

Comment: Usually, when your mro is is inconsistent, this points to a conceptual problem (or hasty coding ;-). Inspecting cls.__mro__ often shows the problem quite quickly.

Answer (score -1):

I met the same situation - I want to slipt my class to 2 files.
the reason is that - I want part 1 for GUI layout, only layout
and another file keeps all function.
like c#'s Partial class. one for XAML and another one for functions.

Answer (score -2):

First off, I don't see how splitting the class into multiple files makes editing any easier. A decent IDE should be able to find any method easily whether in one file or multiple; if you're not using a decent IDE, splitting the class means the maintainer has to guess which file a given method is in, which sounds harder rather than easier.

More fundamentally, this class - so large that you want a special language feature just to support its weight - sounds fundamentally broken. How many lines of code are we talking about? Almost certainly, it would be a better idea to do one of:

- Refactor duplicated code into fewer, more general primitives
- Define a base class and extend it with subclasses as Karoly Horvath suggests in comments (this is the closest thing to the 'partial classes' that you're asking for that I would endorse)
- Define a few separate classes to encapsulate different parts of this
  class's functionality, and compose this class of instances of those
  smaller ones.