# Foreign Key in Django model

Tags: python, django

Here is my situation: `SubCategory` has foreign key to `Topic` and `Topic` has foreign key to `SubCategory`.

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=110)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    ordering = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
    num_topics = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    num_posts = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    last_topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='+')


class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
```

When I run this code, it gives the following error:

```
NameError: name 'Topic' is not defined.
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 12):

Either put `Topic` in quotes: `"Topic"`

```
last_topic = models.ForeignKey("Topic", related_name='+')
```

or put the `Topic` class above the `SubCategory` class

Comment: I'd like to point out that the '<app_name>.<model_name>' syntax exists as well. Thus, 'auth.User' is an easy way to make a foreign key to django.contrib.auth.models.User

Comment: Yea exactly, that's useful when the model you are referencing isn't in the current file. Also when you are trying to avoid circular imports. When the model *is* in the current file you can forgo the app reference

Comment: what does the related_name='+' do?

Comment: @RakeshGopal as [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) say it tells Django not to create backward relation

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Topic is declared after Subcategory and hence it is not available when Subcategory is defined.

Python has no partial class declaration or forward declaration. But you can use the **init** method to achieve something similar. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638446/is-there-any-python-equivalent-to-partial-classes) for details.

Comment: Languages like C++ has the feature of Forward Declaration. Does Python has something similar ?

Comment: @Phoenix, not quite, but can get close using __init__. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the models with quotes:

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=110)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    ordering = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('User')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='+')
    num_topics = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    num_posts = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    last_topic = models.ForeignKey('Topic', related_name='+')


class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey("SubCategory")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('User')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='+')
```

Comment: That's what the top answer proposed, 3 years ago. Please keep your answers useful.

Answer (score -1):

There is several solutions to your problem: you could either define a back reference, from `SubCategory` to `Topic` through the `related_name` `ForeignKey` attribute, or simply pass the name of your ForeignKey model as a string.

Solution 1:

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=110)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    ordering = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    ...
    last_topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='subcategory')
```

Solution 2:

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=110)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    ordering = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
    num_topics = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    num_posts = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    last_topic = models.ForeignKey("Topic", related_name='+')


class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')

    ...
```