# How to split python class into multiple files

Tags: python, code-structure

I have a web service written in Python that has a class that contains handlers for client requests. Due to protocol complexity the number of handlers is high. All handlers are called inside separate thread (Controller class which is a subclass of Thread). To reduce the class size I've defined handlers in separate modules. The end result is below:

```
from handlers.main_handlers import delete_project, ...
class Controller(Thread):
    _handle_delete_project = delete_project.handle_delete_project
    ...

    def run():
        while not self._stopped:
            ...
            self._handle_delete_project(...)
            ...
```

Is there a more Pythonic way do to this? I mean to split a class into multiple files with a better pattern.

Comment: Do the handlers need to be methods? Why not just make them functions and spread them out over as many files as you like?

Comment: Perhaps you'd be better at [codereview.se], where you can provide more context and get more thorough feedback?

Comment: @RolandSmithYes, they need to be methods because they need access to context that is part of the Controller object and should be shared between all handlers.

Comment: @jonrsharpeI did not know about Code Review at the moment when I've created this question. But I think this place is also not so bad for such questions.

Comment: This question is answered by [Is there any Python equivalent to partial classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638446/is-there-any-python-equivalent-to-partial-classes).