# How to distribute python classes into different source files without creating many modules?

Tags: python-3.x, module, package, directory-structure

I have a few related classes sitting in a package like this:

```
\cool
  \__init__.py
    class CoolObj: ...
    class CoolStr(CoolObj): ...
    class CoolName(CoolStr): ...
    class CoolSound(CoolObj): ...
```

And I use these classes like this:

```
import cool
cn = cool.CoolName()
...
```

This `__init__.py` file is getting too long. It would be nice if I could put each class in each of their own file like this:

```
\cool
    \__init__.py
    \cool_obj.py
        class CoolObj: ...
    \cool_str.py
        class CoolStr(CoolStr): ...
    \cool_name.py
        class CoolName(CoolStr): ...
    \cool_sound.py
        class CoolSound(CoolObj): ...
```

However, this way, these files becomes *modules* and I'd have to use them as below, which is a little verbose.

```
from cool import cool_obj, cool_str, cool_name, cool_sound
cn = cool_name.CoolName()
```

Is there anyway that can put source code in separate file while still be able to refer to them with concise syntax like I do now?

Better even, is there anything in `python` like *partial class* in `C#` that allows you to spread implementation of the same class in different files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `__init__.py` you can do the imports to shorten how you use them elsewhere. So a line in `__init__.py` could be

```
from cool_name import CoolName
```

And later on you could do

```
from cool import CoolName
```

You may also want to look at [`__all__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python) as another way of solving this problem. You could import all sorts of stuff in the `cool.__init__.py` module and as long as you include an `__all__` you can explicitly specify what objects will be exported.

Regarding partial classes, I am almost sure Python does not support this kind of functionality through regular class definitions. You could hack it together by injecting different functions into a class at runtime, but that would certainly be messy. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638446/is-there-any-python-equivalent-to-partial-classes) answer takes a deeper look at that path.

Comment: Is it fair to say, whatever is imported in the `__init__.py` of a certain package,  becomes something that can be used as if it was defined in that package?

Comment: That's exactly right. If inside of `__init.py__` you defined an object `SomeValue = 42`, it would be equivalent to if you had defined it in some other module and instead imported it into `__init__.py` with `from other_module import SomeValue`. That's generally true for all python modules, but `__init__.py` has the benefit of making it importable from the _package_. The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) have extensive information about the distinction.